# Combinatorics - how many elements in a product.

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the product $(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^4$
How many elements of the form $x_j^2x_k^2$ will this product produce?
It says $\binom{4}{2}\binom{n}{2}$ in the answers, but I just can't see why do we need the $\binom{4}{2}$?
It is basically asking "how many possibilities are there for choosing two objects with no repetition and no order out of a box with $n$ objects in it?", so that should be $\binom{n}{2}$, where did the $\binom{4}{2}$ come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are $\binom{n}{2}$ choices of $j$ and $k$. For each of those choices, the coefficient in the multinomial theorem is
$$
\frac{4!}{\underbrace{0!0!0!\dots2!\dots0!0!\dots2!\dots0!0!}_{n-2\text{ zeroes, and }2\text{ twos}}}
$$

---

**Another Approach**

For each of the $\binom{n}{2}$ choices of $j$ and $k$, there are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to pick two factors to supply $x_j$ and the other two factors to supply $x_k$.
$$
(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n)
$$

Comment: I think I understand it a lot...but I still have a little doubt...would you please extend the solution a little more?

Comment: @Hawk: I've added a second approach

Comment: That is another good approach...but I will need to think about it myself...it is a little advanced to me...thanks!